# passing input to external application using python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Currently, I have a Python application which opens (via subprocess) an executable, waits for the user to input certain values In console window(command prompt) and perform a calculation, and then, upon closing this executable, reads in the output file back into my Python application for further processing.

I would like, however, to pass variables directly from my application and input these into the entry blocks on the external GUI.

Is this possible?